# how to save authentication cookie while doing POST login into the server

Tags: python

I am trying to login into the server via post with my python script, but it is not working although when i am doing the same POST via postman it is working fine. I believe my python script is not saving the authentication cookie information or may be i have to add some more fields in my payload.  I am at very very beginner level of programming so please guide me how i can save that authentication cookie which i can further use in my next GET, POST requests.

When i run this POST request via postman. I simply give username and password in the body and i got the following successful response

> {
>       "ErrorCode": 0,
>       "Data": {
>           "role": "admin",
>           "_id": "7c9e7mdf4d249212282480zb",
>           "name": "test5"
>       }
>   }

but when I run below mentioned Python script, I am getting

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">  
500 Internal Server error
```

Please find below mentioned my python script

```
import requests

url = "http://172.125.169.21/api/user/login"

payload = "{\"name\": \"test5\", \"password\": \"Hello123\"}"

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload)

print(response.text)

print(response.headers)
```

Comment: This question needs to mention the server's API specification to have any chance to be answered usefully. Would you care to add it?

Comment: In the documentation of REST API for this Server , It is mentioned that it requires a valid username and password. It uses JSON format. One more thing when i run this hard coded token in my script , it works . i got this code from Postman

Comment: " import requests

url = "http://172.125.169.21/api/user/login"


payload = "{\n\t\"name\" : \"test5\",\n\t\"password\" : \"Hello123\"\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "2f261255-csea-f230-d47e-r54c0c8dav76"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

Comment: @Pablo Oilva. One more thing i found in documentation that Using curl, that                                                                                                          
 we may save the authentication information as a cookie to allow subsequent requests to be accepted automatically.

curl -d'{"name":"<username>":"password":"<user password>")' -c cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://12.221.62.60/api/user/login

curl -b cookies.txt http://12.221.62.60/api/case/test2/rerun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the requests library in python, the data object takes a python dict object, not a JSON string. If you were to edit your code to:

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://172.125.169.21/api/user/login"
payload = {"name": "test5", "password": "Hello123"}
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json"}
response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)
# the json parameter should handle encoding for you
print(response.text)
print(response.headers)
```

Cookies are available to you in the cookies parameter of the response object. See [the requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) for more information.

```
print(json.dumps(response.cookies, separators=(",",":"), indent = 4))
```

This should pretty print the cookie(s) you've received. You can use requests' [session handling abilities](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) or a variable to store this information, however you choose. We'll save these cookies to a requests cookiejar:

```
cookies = response.cookies
```

and we'll use those cookies in the authorization check or any other requests:

```
auth_check_url = "172.125.169.21/api/user/checkLogin"
response = requests.get(auth_check_url, cookies=cookies)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work out :(.
One more thing when i run this hard coded token in my script , it works . i got this code from Postman

import requests 
url = "172.125.169.21/api/user/login"; 
payload = "{\n\t\"name\" : \"test5\",\n\t\"password\" : \"Hello123\"\n}"

headers = { 
'Content-Type': "application/json", 
'Cache-Control': "no-cache", 
'Postman-Token': "2f261255-csea-f230-d47e-r54c0c8dav76" 
        } 
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers) 
print(response.text)

Comment: Without more information about the server's API specs, it's going to be hard to troubleshoot. When you tried to run the script I provided, what error did it return? It's possible that the server requires that you set a content type header. I'm editing my answer to include that.

Comment: Please find the error mentioned below . Yeah may be you are right . yes please edit it with header .

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</title>
            <style type="text/css">
              html {background-color: #eee; font-family: sans-serif;}
              body {background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    padding: 15px; margin: 15px;}
              pre {background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</h1>

Comment: <p>Sorry, the requested URL <tt>&#039;http://172.125.169.21/api/user/login&#039;</tt>
               caused an error:</p>
            <pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
              <h2>Exception:</h2>
              <pre>TypeError(&quot;&#039;NoneType&#039; object is not subscriptable&quot;,)</pre>
              <h2>Traceback:</h2>
              <pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;./lib/bottle.py&quot;, line 861, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File &quot;./lib/bottle.py&quot;, line 1737, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)

Comment: File &quot;./lib/bottle.py&quot;, line 1737, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File &quot;/ftscode/pyweb/restful_api.py&quot;, line 173, in serve_user_login
    user_name = login_user[&#039;name&#039;]
TypeError: &#039;NoneType&#039; object is not subscriptable
</pre>
        </body>
    </html>

{'Date': 'Tue, 09 Jan 2018 17:04:25 GMT', 'Content-Length': '1345', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Server': 'FTS2KD311237757'}

Comment: Assuming these are your server logs, it looks like the login_user object isn't getting set.

Comment: yes these are the logs ,  One more thing i found in documentation that 
                                                                                                            
          Using curl, that we may save the authentication information as a cookie to allow subsequent requests to be accepted automatically. curl -d'{"name":"<username>":"password":"<user password>")' -c cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" 12.221.62.60/api/user/login                curl -b cookies.txt 12.221.62.60/api/case/test2/rerun –

Comment: Try using json=payload instead of data=payload in your request. It's possible that it's expecting a different encoding on the serverside.

Comment: I tried this one and it is working fine  and i believe now it also store that cookie value for my further GET and POST requests etc ?:

Comment: import requests
url = "http://172.125.169.21/api/user/login"
payload = "{\n\t\"name\" : \"test5\",\n\t\"password\" : \"Hello123\"\n}"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
   }
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
print(response.headers)

Comment: Updated my answer to include more information on cookie handling. Glad you got this working!

Comment: Thank you so much Jack. Your code works . One last thing . After your code , I added a simple get request code mentioned below but i got the error . although i got msg of successful login by running ur code so after this code,it should show me successful login msg.                                                                                                                                              
 urll = "http://172.125.169.21/api/user/checkLogin"
 response = requests.request("GET", urll)
 print(response.text)
------------------
{"ErrorCode": -1, "ErrorMessage": "No session data"}

Comment: Can you provide the response.text, response.headers, and response.cookies returns from the login? It's possible that the server is returning a value that you need to include in the header of subsequent requests, perhaps a session ID

Comment: {"ErrorCode": 0, "Data": {"role": "admin", "_id": "7b4e6daf4d239203395671ed", "name": "test5"}}
                                                                                                         
{'Content-Length': '95', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Set-Cookie': 'sid="!FIyhrxqgCwHdM6fn3kS7Fv==?gASVJAAAAAAAAACMA3NpZJSMGDVhNTUxNWU1NGQyMzkyMDIyODIzODdLvJSGUD7="; Path=/; SameSite=Lax', 'Server': 'FTS5GK3116033049', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Date': 'Tue, 09 Jan 2018 19:20:05 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'None', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}

Comment: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie sid="!FIyhrxqgCwHdM6fn3kS7Fv==?gASVJAAAAAAAAACMA3NpZJSMGDVhNTUxNWU1NGQyMzkyMDIyODIzODdLvJSGUD7=" for 172.125.169.21/>]>

Comment: {"ErrorCode": -1, "ErrorMessage": "No session data"}

Comment: Again, you'll have to see the documentation of the server you're sending the request to, but it seems to expect the sid value in the header sent back to the server. Try adding "cookies = {"sid": response.cookies["sid"]}" before you do your auth check

Comment: As per documentation , there are no parameters required for this GET request. Do you know where exactly i have to add this ""cookies = {"sid": response.cookies["sid"]}"  in the code ?

Comment: Thank you so much. It  is working. Really appreciate that. GOD bless you :)

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would mark a right answer for this question!

Comment: I just did. Thanks